# local hyper tor is zero

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hallo,

in a proof I read an argument which used the following "fact" which was no further explained:

if you have a closed point $x$ on a smooth projective variety over a field $X$ and denote with $k(x)$ the skyskraper sheaf in the point $x$ with the residue class field of $x$ as skyskraper and a coherent sheaf $F$, then one has that the local hypertor

$\tau \omicron r^{-p}(F,k(x))$

is zero for p greater than zero.

Can someone explain why that is the case?
I dont know if it is relevant that on $X$ every coherent sheaf has a locally free bounded resolution.

Thanks

Comment: I can't explain why it's true because it isn't unless $F$ is locally
free at $x$. I assume that $Tor_{-p}= Tor_p$.
(I didn't downvote, in case you worry about that.)

Comment: I mean $Tor^{-p}= Tor_p$

Comment: ok, thanks. then I'll see if there is some additional hypotheses in the proof which guarantees local freeness or so.